# Specify a host header with httpclient

Tags: ruby

I am using httpclient in ruby, and I am trying to figure out how to use a custom host header.

An example of a use case would be:
- test system is not yet in dns.
- I am trying to get a url by ip, but I need to pass a host header.

I know I can hack my hosts file if needed, but would be nice to be able to do this with httpclient and ruby.

Here is the logic so far:

```
url = 'http://10.0.0.1'
res = HTTPClient.new
content = res.get(url, :follow_redirect => true)
```

Help much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
res.get(url, nil, Host: 'arbitrary_host_here')
```

[reference](https://github.com/nahi/httpclient/commit/58bde3a1c2118272a85a5dc46dca76f8317929c2#diff-d4e81ecb29c85e5026ba137a225d4900R130)

#### Test

Server code:

```
# server.py
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return ('headers: {}\n'.format(request.headers))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8088, debug=True)
```

Client code:

```
# client.rb
require 'httpclient'

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8088'
res = HTTPClient.new
content = res.get(url, nil, Host: 'arbitrary_host_here')
puts content.body
```

Start server with `python server.py` and run client with `ruby client.rb`. STDOUT:

```
headers: User-Agent: HTTPClient/1.0 (2.8.3, ruby 2.5.0 (2017-12-25))
Date: Wed, 14 Mar 2018 14:49:22 GMT
Host: arbitrary_host_here
Accept: */*
```